# How do you put an image at the start of a paragraph in groff mom?

Tags: groff

I'm trying to place a small image, about the height of two lines, at the beginning of a paragraph...kind of like how a drop-cap is placed. I've tried `.PSPIC` and `.PDFIMAGE` with different combinations of their arguments, but the result is always the same: the image pushed the text downward so it begins at the start of the line.

For reference, this is what I'm going for (originally [from here](https://www.jagregory.com/abrash-black-book/#understanding-high-performance), 5th paragraph down).

[image: Drop caps with image]

Comment: I'm not sure if the `PSPIC` or `PDFIMAGE` macros support what you are looking for. However, if you don't get any answers here, I recommend you try emailing the GNU groff mailing list with your question. In my experience, the people on that mailing list are friendly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to fudge things a little, but you can use some base troff commands to return back to the image and draw an empty drop character over it. I created a square 80x80 image from imagemagick with:

```
convert -size 100x100 magick:rose +repage -scale 80x80'!' image.pdf
```

Then included it in a mom document in this way:

```troff
.PP
.fl
.mk x
.PDF_IMAGE -L image.pdf 1.9c 1.9c 
'sp |\nxu+1
.DROPCAP "\h'2c'" 3
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod...
```

The troff part is `.fl` to flush, `.mk x` to mark this place in register x, `'sp |\nxu+1` to go back to the absolute position in number register x, unscaled, plus a fudge of 1 line.
Also, the `.DROPCAP` character is a troff horizontal movement of 2 centimetres, instead of a visable character like `X`. The `.PID_IMAGE` is left adjusted and has fixed width and height of 1.9 cm.
This gave the result:

[image: dropcaps]